# Does the interviewer really not know his subject's name?

Tags: plot-explanation, citizenfour

In the movie *Citizenfour* the interviewer asks a weird question to *Edward Snowden*, right in the middle of their interview:

> Sorry, I don't know your name.

They are making a documentary on him and **they don't know his name?** Is there some joke behind it? Why does he say that?

Comment: [-So I don't know who you
are or anything about you.](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=citizenfour)
-Ok. I work for Booz Allen
Hamilton, defense contractor.
I am sort of on loan to NSA, I
don't talk to Booz Allen boss,
I don't get tasking from
Booz Allen, it's all from NSA.
-So, I don't know your name.
-Oh, sorry, my name is Edward Snowden,
I go by Ed.
Edward Joseph Snowden is the full name.
(spelling) S. N. O. W. D. E. N..
-And where are you from?
-I'm originally... I was
born in North Carolina,
small town, Elizabeth City.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He seems to asking Snowden to go back to first principles, to tell the camera about himself as a person. He then follows it up with a [series of questions](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=citizenfour) about his family and upbringing.

I've added some bracketing to [hopefully] make things clearer

> **Q:** *So [pretend that] I don't know who you are or anything about you.*
>
> **Snowden:** *Okay. Um... I work for Booz Allen Hamilton, a defense contractor, I'm sort of on loan to NSA. I don't talk to a Booz Allen
>   boss, I don't get tasking from Booz Allen, it's all from NSA.*
>
> **Q:** *Sorry, I don't [even] know your name [yet]*
>
> **Snowden:** *Oh, sorry! I, uh... my name is Edward Snowden.*